# How to debug an ASP.NET 5 web app in local IIS not Express

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-core

So it is super easy to setup debugging for your 4.6 (and <) `ASP.NET` web app in your local `IIS`. However, I do not see any way to do this in `ASP.NET 5`. I see `IIS Express`, `ef`, and `web`. Am I missing something? How can I set it up so that I can push `Play` and have it pull up a Chrome tab and have full debugging of my `web app` in my local `IIS`?

Comment: That hasn't been implemented in the tooling yet, but some folks have gotten it working manually: https://github.com/tuespetre/dnx-watch-iis

Answer (score -1):

If you meant Controller debugging, you just have to make sure you properly have your breakpoints at the lines of codes you've created. After that, all you have to do is to run via IIS Express and you're good to go, VS will automatically prompt you to take a look at the IDE when you have to perform a stepover or etc.

From there you'll be able to check on your code with the various debugging windows in the 'Debug' option on the top bar of VS.

[image: top bar]

By the way, if you made a thorough lookup on the state of local IIS with .NET Core, there is no way as of now to do so..

[How to configure ASP.NET Core 1.0 to use Local IIS instead of IIS Express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38619454/how-to-configure-asp-net-core-1-0-to-use-local-iis-instead-of-iis-express)

And to further emphasize the pointlessness of using local IIS, here's quote from this [article](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/Jun/06/Publishing-and-Running-ASPNET-Core-Applications-with-IIS#RunningIISasaDevelopmentServer-no):

> However, with ASP.NET Core there's little to no reason to be running
>   full IIS during development. Why? Because ASP.NET Core applications
>   aren't actually running inside of IIS. Whether you running called from
>   IIS, IIS Express or whether you do dotnet run directly from the
>   command line - you are running the exact same code and in most cases
>   the exact same execution environment. Running inside of IIS really
>   doesn't buy you anything anymore that you can't easily simulate with a
>   command line environment.

Comment: No, I specifically do NOT want IIS Express, but local IIS.

Comment: I don't see why you want to use local IIS instead. Nevertheless, using local IIS makes no significant difference in .NET already because of .NET Core.

Comment: Because I am working in a solution that has over 20 micro apps and services that all need to be running at the same time. Right now I need to have 20 instances of VS running in order to properly run my application. Instead I would want to have all of them running in Local IIS and just have 1 instance of VS running for the micro app that I am currently working in.

Comment: Project-> Properties -> Debug -> check "Start external program" and click on the ... button, navigate to your .exe of the other program.

Then Make sure in your Solution -> Properties -> MultipleStartup Projects that it's checked.

Comment: `Start external program` may be an option in some older version of `ASP.NET` but it is not an option in `ASP.NET Core`

Answer (score -1):

Maybe not exactly what you need, but you can debug it.

- Before you start debugging, you need to republish the project to the path specified in IIS.
- Browse to any webpage of the app so the process starts.
- Then inside your VS go to `Debug -> Attach to process`. Find and select `dotnet.exe`. There might be several of them, so ticking `Show processes from all users` could reveal a few more records. 
  For example, the pool I use on IIS for .net core apps runs under *NetworkService* identity so it is easy for me to identify the `dotnet.exe` process I need to attach to (*Attach to Process* popup has *User Name* column that contains identity info).

Finally, VS will start debugging. It's similar to the steps for .net framework + attaching to `w3wp.exe`

Comment: This would work but is certainly not as simple as pushing Play.

Comment: Wrong. You don't republish anything to make this work.